# How to assign a value to a ref that has a generic type?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am writing a Vue composable using TypeScript.

It takes in a generic type `T` and a single paramter `path`, and returns a `document` ref.

I've almost got it working but whenever I try to assign a value to the `document` ref it throws an error like this:

```
Type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ id: string; }'.ts(2322)
```

Here is a trimmed down version of the composable:

```
import { ref, Ref } from "vue";
import { projectFirestore } from "@/firebase/config";
import { doc, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";

const getDocument = <T>(
  path: string
): {
  document: Ref<T | null>;
} => {
  const document = ref(null) as Ref<T | null>;
  const docRef = doc(projectFirestore, path);
  onSnapshot(docRef, (doc) => {
    document.value = { //<-- Error here on "document.value"
      ...doc.data(),
      id: doc.id,
    };
  });
  return { document };
};

export default getDocument;
```

It doesn't matter what I assign to `document.value` (strings, an empty object, etc) it always gives a similar error saying it is not assignable to type `T`.

I understand the error is telling me the type `T` could be anything, and therefore it's not safe to assign these things because the type of the things might be not be compatible with type `T`.

But how do I solve this problem? Can I somehow tell TypeScript that type `T` is compatible with other types?

Comment: It's likely `<T extends unknown>`. But in your case you need to define a more specific type you have in mind. If it's an object with id, it's `{ id: string }` like the answer says, and likely needs to be an interface, because you may want to extend the type in places where you use this generic. If it's more specific, it should be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T` is only used in your return type. Your generic is declaring that the resulting Ref is the caller's choice of `T` with no boundaries.

Even if you could specify that `T extends { id: string }` or that your return type is `T & { id: string }`—and you can, using that syntax—you'd have to defeat strong typing at some point, because at runtime `getDocument` won't ever know enough about T to assert that `doc.data()` will be compatible with the particular T that the `getDocument` call infers.

I'd pick one of these three options:

- Remove the generic and return `Ref<{id: string} | null>`, which is type-safe but would force you to use `ref["key"]` notation to check arbitrary unknown keys.
- Keep the generic and trust your calls to `getDocument` to specify the right type, figuring that it's much more likely for your code to introduce bugs than for Firestore to give you an unexpected data type. You'd need to use `as any` to show TypeScript you're deliberately dropping type safety in assigning `document.value`.
- Use a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) that you pass into `getDocument` along with the path. The predicate is a function that would take a single arg and return whether its arg `is T`, which you could check in `onSnapshot` to ensure that your `document` is safe to cast to T or fail with the mitigation/error of your design. This also constrains T so your generic can't be absolutely any type. See example below.

---

```
const getDocument = <T>(
  path: string,
  docPredicate: (doc: any) => doc is T,  // accept predicate
): {
  document: Ref<T & {id: string} | null>;
} => {
  const document = ref(null) as Ref<T & {id: string} | null>;
  const docRef = doc(projectFirestore, path);
  onSnapshot(docRef, (doc) => {
    const data = doc.data(); // extract to local variable
    if(docPredicate(data)) { // convince TS data is type T
      document.value = {
        ...data,             // integrate as expected
        id: doc.id,
      };
    }
  });
  return { document };
};

interface Foo { a: string, b: number }
function isFoo(doc: any): doc is Foo {
  // TODO: check that doc has {a: string, b: number}
  return true;
}

const fooDoc = getDocument("bar", isFoo);
if (fooDoc.document.value) {
  console.log(fooDoc.document.value.a);
  console.log(fooDoc.document.value.id);
}
```

[Playground before](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYGwhgzhAEBKCmAzAPAFQHzQN7QG5hAFd4BCALmlQG5oBfAWACgATeUMAJ3mkUIDtgAFwCWAez7QuKDAApBFVAEoKCaeipNW7Lj35CxE8QGU+YAA4QAFqMEypFMHwCeAGmjACIAEZhgAawoZZlFgChxhZgoIQQ5hPgBzN2YwQTAZZWgAeS8AKzZBOkVoAF5MXFEIjPKIjRY2cB1eARFxaGDgGTMOUTyhKJi4xOgzFMt+2ISMnGTU9Ip+Pz5RAHcJWlqtBu58DmHu3sEAMWEuaNEuccHapmBxaOh4+EEAERDCAFt4PgLi6DR0GRMaDDUaXBJMKZAtpvT7fFRINDQAA+0D4hBAIHUTFoJUwWChtz493aHy+P0kSBkaIxRUgcARqGRqPRmNqwMJxJCqhK0I6XR6+WOp0E53gbhGgksijZ0GMpgs1ls7VUbiCISKpWwUOBJNhggAdPgiNxfjgAPRm5AAWit0AAohxurtLPAdK0AES6smGgjEd3a4HQfXB9r6mZpRQuAPAiIUUMRKOMQN0GW0aVQriCQgcCTTGFklPY66MeAADzM5wKrEQYHRBUeL3z3yoQA) => [Playground after](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#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-G4kx4VDXmxX5HhecDWRkAAiHwOAMtwyNQ-9GGbaAZEQDSM2VVl1wIYgB3lO5RHrdNy3iWz7OATM9LXDdiHTPsA1tTz4G80RfLs0RNMC4BV0EZzN1fZhLJ-IA)

Comment: Thanks for explaining in a clear manner. Has helped me understand. In my Vue SFC I am creating an interface that is passed into `getDocument` as a generic. Removing the generic, and therefore also the interface, causes all sorts of other Vue template errors. So I'm forced into keeping the generic and using your last solution, but I've been warned many times against using `any` so it makes me wary.

Comment: @TinyTiger You're right to be wary, but if Firestore can return an arbitrary type, then the best you can do is let `as any` remind you that the code is unsafe. Admittedly there's a third option using type predicates, which I'll edit in.

Comment: I'm trying to use your type predicate solution which is looking like this `const isDoc = (doc: unknown): doc is { id: string } => { return typeof doc === "object"; };`. But it doesn't remove the error from `document.value`. See current code here: https://pastebin.com/mMHsN9Je. Any idea what I've done wrong? Mind adding code to your answer to show how I can use the type predicate correctly?

Comment: @TinyTiger I've reproduced with stubs in the playground and added that to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I just discovered another solution.

Since Firebase provides a `DocumentData` interface, I used that in the `document` ref and return type.

Doing so allowed me to remove the `T` generic entirely.

This makes it a much simpler composable function without the need to create and pass in my own interfaces. It resolves the errors in this composable, and the errors in the Vue SFC template when called.

Here is the full code:

```
import { ref, Ref } from "vue";
import { projectFirestore } from "@/firebase/config";
import {
  doc,
  onSnapshot,
  DocumentSnapshot,
  DocumentData,
} from "firebase/firestore";

const getDocument = (
  path: string
): {
  document: Ref<DocumentData | null>;
} => {
  const document = ref<DocumentData | null>(null);
  const docRef = doc(projectFirestore, path);
  onSnapshot(docRef, (doc: DocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>) => {
    if (doc.data()) {
      document.value = {
        ...doc.data(),
        id: doc.id,
      };
    }
  });
  return { document };
};

export default getDocument;
```

Comment: DocumentData is definitely the right interface as far as Firestore is concerned, but it's just [a mapped type from `string` to `any`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/firestore-types/index.d.ts#L20). If you already represent the schema of your intended object as an interface, then checking it with a predicate and passing it as a generic would give you more type safety than this solution.

Comment: Oh I see! Interesting to know